# Best way to insert loader icon if images has not been fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

given the html structure:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img id="firstslide" src="img/verybig.jpg">
</div>
```

I wonder if there is an easy and simple way to check

1. if an image is currenly being loaded and insert into div a load icon and
2. has finished loading and show the fully loaded picture

Any hints with that?

Comment: Are you working with transparent images? do you know what size your images are? One way to do this is just give each `img` tag a background image.

Comment: @BrianGlaz thanks for asking! I have very big images...like 2 MB...and i hate it when this image i building up slowly...instead i like to have a little loding icon as long as the image is loading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjfvZ/60/

If you're using jQuery:

```
<div id="loading">Loading</div>
<img id="image" src="image.png" style="display:none"/>

<script>
    $('#image').load(function()
    {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i try to build a fiddle for this...so everyone can follow

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't including jQuery in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! Now its included but it it's still not working...http://jsfiddle.net/FjfvZ/8/

Comment: thanks Jonathan! Here is a working fiddle for whom it may concern...http://jsfiddle.net/FjfvZ/60/

Answer (score 3):

I would do it from CSS, as setting the loader animation image as the background of the selected images:

CSS:

```
img.loader {
  background: url(loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img id="firstslide" class="loader" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="img/verybig.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious: In addition to `50% 50%` wouldn't `center` also work?  I feel like `50% 50%` will position the left and top borders to the center, not the center of the image to the center...

Comment: No, it's the same: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position

Comment: thanks fpr the answer...but isn't the pic still slowly building up AND showing the icon? Or does the image show up just when its fully loaded and one can have an "remove" effect...

Comment: It does not affect the loading of the image. The loaded image will simply overlap the background (loader image).

Comment: @KARASZIIstván hmm thats not what i was thinking of...i hate this when the image is slowly building up...instead i want to have an icon as long as loading continues

Comment: Ohh, I see. Then my solution is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use an image preloader plugin:

http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/

This will give you control to do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small loading image as the background image which will be covered up by the actual image once it has loaded.

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2QtJw/)**.

Comment: thanks a lot! But i my case the html image is already in the dom. I could hide it and show it again though... but what i need is and event or sth that fires during the images is loading...

Answer (score 0):

this provides a simple n good solution:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload